# Convert to multiple checkbox from an existing comma separated input in Angular 6

Tags: angular

Currently, the input field accepts comma separated value. However, I want it to be converted into a multiple checkbox.

Here's the current HTML:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="tempTargetAudience">
```

I would like to change this HTML to:

```
    <div>
      <label for="check1">
        <input type="checkbox" id="check1" name="option1" value="something" checked>Option 1
      </label>
      <label for="check2">
        <input type="checkbox" id="check2" name="option2" value="something">Option 2
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="check3" name="option3" value="something">Option 3
      </label>
    </div>
```

Here's the .TS file that processes the data

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.tempTags = this.data.tags ? this.data.tags.join(',') : '';
    this.tempTargetAudience = this.data.targetAudience ? this.data.targetAudience.join(',') : '';
  }
save() {
    this.data.tags = this.tempTags.split(',');
    this.data.targetAudience = this.tempTargetAudience.split(',');
    if (this.data.id) {
      this.edit();
    } else {
      this.add();
    }
  }
```

JSON File

```
"targetAudience": [
  "kids",
  "women",
  "men",
  "others"
],
```

Comment: So what is the issue? Where are you facing issues in changing it to checkboxes? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just save it as an Array like this:

```js
this.tempTargetAudience = this.data.targetAudience;
```

Then loop through it with `*ngFor`, like:

```
<label for="check1" *ngFor=“let audience of tempTargetAudience“>
    <input type="checkbox" id="check1" name="option1" value="something" checked>{{audience}}
</label>
```